# How to test line by line in a file in Python?

Tags: python

I have a' file containing numbers that consist of 8 digits.

I have to read evvery line and if the number is not 8 digits in lenth and containing letters I must print "invalid" next to it.

Here is my code for reading the file but i have no idea how to print the condition next to each number, I would greatly appreciate any help.

```
fname = "Data.txt"
count = 0
with open(fname, "r") as f:
    for line in f:
        count += 1
print("Antal Studentenommers:", count)

myfile = open("Data.txt")
for line in myfile:
    print(line.strip())
myfile.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean the following?

```
fname = "Data.txt"

with open(fname) as myfile:
  for line in myfile:    # Iterate over each line in file fname
    line = line.rstrip() # remove trailing '\n'
    if not line.isdigit() or len(line) != 8:  # check only digits and length equals 8
      print(f'{line} Invalid')
```

**Test**

*File Data.txt*

```
12345678
123456
abc12345
```

*Output*

```
123456 Invalid
abc12345 Invalid
```